# Django | set the default value of a model field to be the email of the logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to display user specific content in my django website and I am one step away from completing this task. In models.py I need the contact_email field to have its default value to be the email of the logged in user. I've tried many methods of doing this but nothing has worked yet.

models.py

```
class Account(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Are you using FilmLink as an employee?')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'is_employee']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("post_jobs", "Can post jobs"),
        ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_perms(self, perm):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

class Job(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, verbose_name="Company/Employer")
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    area_of_filming = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Area Of Filming", default="")
    contact_email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Contact Email', max_length=60, default='')#stuck on setting this default
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def manage_jobs(request):
    if request.user.is_employee:
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = JobForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        jobs = Job.objects.filter(contact_email = request.user.email)
        context = {"form":form, "jobs":jobs}
        return render(request, 'employer/manage-jobs.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class JobForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('company', 'description', 'role', 'area_of_filming', 'contact_email')
```

Comment: "*the contact_email is in the form, a user can put in any email that doesn't = request.user.email. Therefore, it would filter out that job as well.*" Show how you use `JobForm`. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can set a default that way.

What you should do instead is, when creating a `Job` object and saving it to database, provide the value of `contact_email` yourself.

You would then be able to later filter the `Job` entries based on `contact_email` field.

```py
# Creating a Job object
job = Job()
job.column1 = value
job.contact_email = request.user.email

# In other view, where you need to filter
jobs = Job.objects.filter(contact_email=request.user.email)
```

**A random thought**:

if the only reason you want that `contact_email` field there is to be able to apply the filter to get all Job objects for that particular user, then you can just filter with `user` field too.

```py
jobs = Job.objects.filter(user=request.user)
context = {"form":form, "jobs":jobs, 'contact_email': request.user.email}
return render(request, 'employer/manage-jobs.html', context)
```

Comment: I initially was going to filter by user rather than contact_email, but I tried the line 'jobs=Job.objects.filter(user=request.user)' and I wasn't returned any data. Also, when trying this I had a foreignkey to my custom user model in the Job model. When I saw that this didn't work I decided I'd filter by the contact_email. To do this I was going to set the default value of the contact_email to the email field of my user model. Once I did that, I was then going to remove contact_email from the form, so it would always be the request.user.email. But this caused many errors.

Comment: I think my options are going to be to override the save method, or to add a foreignkey to the JOB model inside of the user model

Comment: What do you mean by job.column1 = value?

Comment: I understand exactly what the next line does, but since the contact_email is in the form, a user can put in any email that doesn't = request.user.email. Therefore, it would filter out that job as well. (Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in the beginning)

Comment: @Ruairí your models appear to be fine the way they are. You mention that `contact_email` is on a user facing form. Can't you just ignore the value of that field and go on to use `request.user.email` when saving that `Job` object? With your current description, I can't seem to see why you wouldn't be able to just ignore the value from form, and just use the email of the logged in user. If you have additional info to share, perhaps more code, share those too as it is very hard to tell currently what exactly is the roadblock. Cheers!

Comment: @PSSolanki Are you talking about making a foreignkey to the  user model's email?